# Using outer margins for wide content in xsl-fo double-side layout

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have content (for example, a table) which is too wide for the content region. How to ask an XSL-FO formatter to use the space from the outer margin?

[image]

For a one-side layout it is easy, I can specify a negative value to `margin-right`. For a double-side layout I could imagine a property `margin-outer`, but there is no such thing.

Comment: Which XSL FO processor are you using? You could accomplish your task with a formatter like RenderX and using fo:float which takes alternate values of "inside" and "outside" (instead of "left" and "right") to accomplish this layout.

Comment: @kevin-brown I'm using FOP. Thanks for pointing to XEP. Do you know if other processors have also this feature?

Comment: AH Formatter from Antenna House has `inside` and `outside` plus `alternate` (for use when there's multiple columns).  See https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf63/ahf-float.html#axf.float-x